# Database Snapshots with Toad for Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, toad

I have a rather large database (1100 tables or so). I'm interested in taking a snapshot of the database, doing some work in the application, taking another snapshot and comparing the two to figure out which tables got touched. I'm using TOAD for Oracle. Is something like this possible, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_comparison.htm#ARPLS868

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use TOAD but I think it has very little to do with what you want.

Assuming only the one application is running I think you could check which tables were accessed by it checking the `DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS` the tables need to have `MONITORING` attribute set. See docs for [ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2097.htm#i1591024) You can then combine this with enabling Fine-Grained Auditing on tables you want to monitor. This will allow you to monitor INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE queries, looking at bind variables and much more. Check the docs [About Fine-Grained Auditing](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/audit_config.htm#DBSEG903) You need to have Enterprise Edition to use Fine-Grained Auditing

Do you need to revert the changes done by the application?

If so the best and easiest approach to revert the changes would be Oracle Flashback technology. It simply allows you to check previous state of tables based on your flashback retention target. Again the docs are quite overwhelming on the subject [Using Flashback Database and Restore Points](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/flashdb.htm#BRADV71000) and [Oracle Flashback query](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr002.htm) Flashback technology is an extra feature which has to be bought from Oracle.

You could in theory do this also by doing database point-in-time recovery, this is done through RMAN check the docs for complete information on this [Database Backup and Recovery Basics 10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr006.htm) This is an overkill and I don't recommend it for your scenario.

I think the best approach to your problem is to add or enable logging of SQL queries on the application side.